# Struggling to get rails server running with Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle, apple-m1, ffi

Setting up a rails server. When running the following command:

```
bundle exec rails server
```

I get the following error:

```
dlopen(/Users/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): symbol not found in flat namespace '_ffi_prep_closure' - /Users/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/lib/ffi_c.bundle (LoadError)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Environment: Mac OS X 12.3, CPU: M1 MAX.

Answer (score 0):

Can You try running following

```
gem uninstall ffi
brew reinstall libffi
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"
gem install ffi
```

credits - https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/687#issuecomment-468005152

**OR**

you can try reinstalling gem by

`gem install ffi -- --disable-system-libffi`

Hope one of these solutions resolve your issue

Thanks.

Comment: Tried both with still no success

Comment: ruby version and rails framework version?

Comment: Ruby version is 2.6.6

Comment: As per ffi docs on github  - Use of the system libffi can be enforced by:

Comment: FInal try, As per ffi docs on github  - Use of the system libffi can be enforced by:
`gem install ffi -- --enable-system-libffi        # to install the gem manually
bundle config build.ffi --enable-system-libffi   # for bundle install`